# How to add 5% percent Gaussian noise to image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, noise

let define that:

*The "percent noise" number represents the percent ratio of the standard deviation of the white Gaussian noise versus the signal for whole image.*

Assume I have a brain image, I want to add **5% Gaussian noise** to whole image (tissues) by Matlab code:

```
I=imread('brain91.png'); I=rgb2gray(I);I=double(I);
I = I - min(I(:));
I = I / max(I(:));

%// Add noise to image
v = 0.05*var(I(:));
I_noisy = imnoise(I, 'gaussian', 0, v);
I_noisy=255.*I_noisy;
subplot(121);imshow(I,[]);subplot(122);imshow(I_noisy,[])
```

The figure show original image (left side) and noise image in right side. Do you think that my implementation is correct for above definition? - (about 5% Gaussian noise by set v = 0.05*var(I(:)))

[image]

Comment: Since the standard deviation is the square root of the variance, shouldn't it be `v = 0.05^2 * var(I(:))`?

Comment: Thank  dasdingonesin, It is really good point. However, I am not sure. Need someone verify it. But I think that var function return variation of image and the sentence 5% that means add 5% for variation, not sqrt of variation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Ander Biguri and dasdingonesin have correct assertions.  Your code is certainly adding Gaussian noise to the image properly, but make sure you account for the actual variance by squaring the `0.05` in your `var` calculation.

Alternatively, you can use [`std`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/std.html) instead of `var` and square the entire calculation to get the same thing:

```
I=imread('brain91.png'); I=rgb2gray(I);I=double(I);
I = I - min(I(:));
I = I / max(I(:));

%// Add noise to image
%v = (0.05^2)*var(I(:)); %// Option #1
v = (0.05*std(I(:)))^2; %// Option #2
I_noisy = imnoise(I, 'gaussian', 0, v);
I_noisy=255.*I_noisy;
subplot(121);imshow(I,[]);subplot(122);imshow(I_noisy,[])
```

Comment: Yes. I was mistaken between variation and standard derivation. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. 
I have used slicer packages for adding or removing noise. You can try to compare your results with it :

[image: slicer gaussian filter]