# Which one is the correct way of simulating addtive Gaussian noise

Tags: matlab, image-processing, noise

I have a noise-free image `I`. I want to simulate the additive Gaussian noise (zero mean, and variation `v`) `n` added to the image. The output of the [model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_white_Gaussian_noise) is:

```
Z = I + n
```

To simulate it, we have two ways:

1. create a gaussian noise and add it to image,
2. use `imnoise` function in MATLAB.

I used both ways, but they gave different results. Could you determine which one is correct? Why aren't they equivalent? In my knowledge, I think `imnoise` is correct one.

In my simulation, I use a definition of noise percent as

> The "percent noise" number represents the percent ratio of the standard deviation of the Gaussian noise versus the signal for whole image.

```
I = imread('eight.tif');
[rows cols]=size(I);
I = double(I);
I = I - min(I(:));
I = I / max(I(:));
%% Percentage ratio
noise_per=0.4; %40 percent noise
%% Add noise to image
v = (noise_per*std(I(:)))^2 %// Option #2
%% Add noise by manual way
n=normrnd(0,v,[rows cols]);
I_noise1=I+n;
%% Add noise by imnoise func.
I_noise2 = imnoise(I, 'gaussian', 0, v);

subplot(131);imshow(n,[]);title('Gaussian noise');
subplot(132);imshow(I_noise1,[]);title('Add Gaussian noise #1');
subplot(133);imshow(I_noise2,[]);title('Add Gaussian noise #2');
```

[image: output]

Comment: I tested your code and got an error in line "I_noise1=I+n;". It says Matrix dimensions must agree. I don't have the original "eight.tif" so I had to use another image

Comment: @VMMF: code above assume a grayscale image (wrong size computed if image was RGB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the fact that `normrnd` takes **standard deviation** as input while `imnoise` expects **variance** (as noted by @mainactual), there is also the issue of data type and the range of values.

There is a note in `imnoise` documentation:

> **Note**: The mean and variance parameters for 'gaussian' noise type is always specified as if the image were of class `double` in the range [0, 1]. If the input image is of class `uint8`, the `imnoise` function converts the image to `double`, adds noise according to the specified type and parameters, and then converts the noisy image back to the same class as the input.

In your case where the input image is already `double` in [0,1] range, this means clipping the output values to [0,1] range after adding the noise.

Also `normrnd` in this case can be replaced with a simple call to `randn`.

Example:

```
% input image
I = imread('eight.tif');
I = im2double(I);  % convert to double in [0,1] range

% noise mean/variance
m = 0;
v = (0.4 * std(I(:)))^2;

% normrnd
noise1 = normrnd(m, sqrt(v), size(I));
I1 = I + noise1;
I1 = max(0, min(I1, 1));  % clip to [0,1] range

% randn
noise2 = randn(size(I))*sqrt(v) + m;
I2 = I + noise2;
I2 = max(0, min(I2, 1));  % clip to [0,1] range

% imnoise
I3 = imnoise(I, 'gaussian', m, v);

% compare
subplot(221), imshow(I),  title('original')
subplot(222), imshow(I1), title('normrnd')
subplot(223), imshow(I2), title('randn')
subplot(224), imshow(I3), title('imnoise')
```

[image: image-gaussian-noise]

Comment: Thank Amro. I read some paper they often give the percent of noise and I just multiply it with variance. Do you think my implementation make sense?

Comment: I think so, I guess it depends on how you define "percent of noise".. Here are some related posts: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/51357-how-can-i-determine-the-percentage-of-noise-given-the-variance-of-imnoise, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31834803/how-to-add-5-percent-gaussian-noise-to-image

Answer (score 1):

I bolded the essential:

> `J = imnoise(I,'gaussian',M,V)` adds Gaussian white noise of mean m and **variance** v to the image I. The default is zero mean noise with 0.01 variance.
>   http://se.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imnoise.html

and

> `R = normrnd(mu,sigma)` generates random numbers from the normal distribution with mean parameter mu and **standard deviation** parameter sigma.
>   http://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/normrnd.html

I think the both ways should be pretty equal and equally correct for your task and any other after the variance is corrected, that is, after

```
I_noise2 = imnoise( I, `gaussian`, 0, v^2 ); % orr sqrt(v) depends...
```