# Is there a method to determine the level of noise in image that preserve original Information as well?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I want to test my algorithm in noisy images. 
I tested Lema image to add Gaussian noise using the following line of Code.

```
cv::randn(nimg, 128, 30);
```

and the result is this.

**Input Image:**

[image]

**Noisy Image:**

[image]

**Question:**

I want to add noise little by little. 
It is hard to determine to what level of noise, i can preserve original information as well.

Anyone can suggest me values of mean and standard deviation to add noise? 
Is there any method to determine level of noise that preserve original information as well? 
Or It is just on Trail basis?

Comment: Use imnoise function and increase the variance parameter in that function. [Here is a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31836415/7659682).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to add noise in image.

Working in C++.

```
    Mat noise = img.clone();
    Scalar meCan, 
           stddev;
    meanStdDev(img, meCan, stddev);
    uchar mean = meCan.val[0], 
          std = stddev.val[0];
    uchar vari = double(pow((double)std, 2));
    cv::randn(noise, 0, ((double)vari* noiseLevel));
    //add noise image into Original Image
    Mat result;
    cv::add(img, noise, result);
```