# Adding noise to image based on pixel value

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, noise, noise-generator

I would like to add gaussian noise to images in greyscale based on percentages
[image]

I'd like to add 5% of any pixel intensity value in the eye area as noise to the whole image, so what i want to do is select any pixel inside the eye region and given their simple pixel intensity add 5% of guassian noise to the entire image.

```
def generate_noisy_image(x, variance):
    noise = np.random.normal(0, variance, (1, x.shape[0]))
    return x + noise

def loadimage(path):
    filepath_list = listdir(path)
    for filepath in filepath_list:
        img = Image.open(path + filepath)
        img = img.resize((81, 150))
        img = np.asarray(img)
        generate_noisy_image(img, 0.025)
        img = Image.fromarray(img)
        img.save('C:/Users/noisy-images/'+filepath, 'JPEG')



loadimage('C:/Users/my_images/')
```

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
> (150,81) (1,150)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-1bebb687f5e7> in <module>
     11 
     12 
---> 13 loadimage('source path from images')
     14 

<ipython-input-96-1bebb687f5e7> in loadimage(path)
      5         img = img.resize((81, 150))
      6         img = np.asarray(img)
----> 7         generate_noisy_image(img, 0.025)
      8         print(generate_noisy_image.shape)
      9         img = Image.fromarray(img)

<ipython-input-95-7cc3346953f6> in generate_noisy_image(x, variance)
      1 def generate_noisy_image(x, variance):
      2     noise = np.random.normal(0, variance, (1, x.shape[0]))
----> 3     return x + noise
```

Comment: The first thing you'll need is the RGB values that you'll use as a reference.  You'll need to do feature identification which isn't trivial.

Comment: The image is in greyscale and the features are already identified, i just took that picture because i couldnt think of any other hehe, for instance i just need an example that takes the value of any pixel in the image and adds some % of noise to the whole image based on that grey value, i should be able to clutch the problem from there

Comment: i edited the question to specify in a simple way my goal

Comment: When copy-pasting an error message, please copy-paste the whole thing, including the stack trace and the information about which line of code produces the error. That makes it so much easier to understand what might me wrong.

Comment: Ok, i updated the question with the stack trace.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you want because your various attempts at explaining it somewhat contradict each other IMHO. So, let's say all your pixels are mid-grey with intensity=128, except for the one pixel whose intensity we are going to consider in order to add noise. Let's say that one pixel has intensity=190. So what happens now - what's the result you expect?

Comment: Then i expect like probability of gaussian noise of 9,5.

Comment: What do you mean *"9,5"*? All the pixels were 128 in my example, what are they afterwards?

Comment: Basically, i would like to do this for python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31834803/how-to-add-5-percent-gaussian-noise-to-image. But its done in matlab.

Comment: I can't read Matlab. Could you say, in plain English, what the pixels will become in my very simple example above please?

Comment: I didnt know the noise was added to image in accordance to the standard deviation/variance, my apologies. I thought noise was added according to pixel value, thats why it looked confusing. But the simplest way i can put it, i just wish to add noise the same way the user in that question did. What i am trying to do is create a dataset with noise to the image in different percentages/levels. 2.0, 2.5, 5.0

Comment: I edited my answer bellow. Does it answer your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very basic example, hack around `np.array`'s dims to make it work.

```py
import numpy as np


def generate_noisy_image(x: np.array, variance: float) -> np.array:
    noise = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=variance, size=x.shape)
    return x + noise


if __name__ == "__main__":
    img_2D = np.random.random(size=(81, 150))
    img_2D_fake = generate_noisy_image(x=img_2D, variance=0.05)

    var = np.var(img_2D_fake - img_2D)
    sigma_by_var = var ** 0.5

    sigma = np.std(img_2D_fake - img2D)


    print(f"variance={var}\nsigma_by_var={sigma_by_var}\nsigma={sigma}")
```

Keep in mind the standard derivation is the root square of the variance. It should print a var ~0.0025 and a std ~0.05 in the above example.

Comment: Im trying to use your code to resized images in PIL and i get the following: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (150,81) (1,150). I added my code to the main post. plshelp

Comment: I had fixed the error few days back, but thanks for the update, i accepted your answer.